# How to get second lowest cost SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Need to find which invoice has the second-lowest total price among invoices that do not include a sale of a FiredAlways stove.

I can manage to get the lowest, but not the second lowest.

What I have:

```
SELECT TOP 1 WITH TIES
I.InvoiceNbr,
I.InvoiceDt,
I.TotalPrice
FROM INVOICE I 
 WHERE EXISTS(
       SELECT TOP 2 WITH TIES
       I.InvoiceNbr
       FROM INVOICE I
       WHERE EXISTS (
             SELECT FK_InvoiceNbr
             FROM INV_LINE_ITEM
             WHERE FK_StoveNbr NOT IN 
                   (SELECT S.SerialNumber
                   FROM STOVE AS S 
                   WHERE S.Type = 'FiredAlways'))
                   ORDER BY I.TotalPrice DESC)
 GROUP BY I.InvoiceNbr, I.InvoiceDt, I.TotalPrice
 ORDER BY I.TotalPrice ASC;
```

Data:

```
[INVOICE](
[InvoiceNbr] [numeric](18, 0) NULL,
[InvoiceDt] [datetime] NULL,
[TotalPrice] [numeric](18, 2) NULL,
[FK_CustomerID] [numeric](18, 0) NULL,
[FK_EmpID] [numeric](18, 0) NULL

[INV_LINE_ITEM](
[LineNbr] [numeric](18, 0) NULL,
[Quantity] [numeric](18, 0) NULL,
[FK_InvoiceNbr] [numeric](18, 0) NULL,
[FK_PartNbr] [numeric](18, 0) NULL,
[FK_StoveNbr] [numeric](18, 0) NULL,
[ExtendedPrice] [numeric](18, 2) NULL

[STOVE](
[SerialNumber] [int] NOT NULL,
[Type] [char](15) NOT NULL,
[Version] [char](15) NULL,
[DateOfManufacture] [smalldatetime] NULL,
[Color] [varchar](12) NULL,
[FK_EmpId] [int] NULL,
```

Wanted Output:

```
Invoice # date         Price
--------- ------------ -------
 206      02/03/2002     28.11
```

Comment: Great job posting sample tables DDL. Now all you need to do to complete your question is to add sample data as DML and desired results.

Comment: Your convoluted query can most likely be replaced by something much simpler with the help of analytic functions.  As the above comment says, please add sample data/output to make your question complete.

Comment: 2nd lowest = `dense_rank() over (ORDER BY I.TotalPrice DESC) = 2`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two general approaches to get the *nth lowest*:

```
DECLARE @tbl TABLE(SomeInt INT);
INSERT INTO @tbl VALUES(10),(2),(35),(44),(52),(56),(27);
```

--Use a `TOP n` on the inner select and a `TOP 1` with a reverse order on the outer:

```
SELECT TOP 1 innertbl.SomeInt
FROM
(
    SELECT TOP 2 SomeInt 
    FROM @tbl
    GROUP BY SomeInt
    ORDER BY SomeInt
) AS innertbl
ORDER BY innertbl.SomeInt DESC;
```

--use a `CTE` with `DENSE_RANK()` (thx to dnoeth for the hint)

```
WITH AddSortNumber AS
(
    SELECT SomeInt
          ,DENSE_RANK() OVER(ORDER BY SomeInt) AS SortNumber
    FROM @tbl 
)
SELECT SomeInt
FROM AddSortNumber
WHERE SortNumber=2
```

Comment: `row_number` will return no row when there are two rows with the lowest value, switch to `dense_rank` instead.

Comment: @dnoeth This is true... Adding `GROUP BY SomeInt` would solve this too...  Will change that

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
WITH cte AS
(
SELECT
I.InvoiceNbr,
I.InvoiceDt,
I.TotalPrice,
dense_rank() over( ORDER BY I.TotalPrice ASC) as dnrnk
FROM INVOICE I 
INNER JOIN 
Inv_LineITEM
ON InvoiceNbr = FK_InvoiceNbr
INNER JOIN
Stove
ON
FK_StoveNbr = SerialNumber
WHERE Type != 'FiredAlways'   
)
select InvoiceNbr,
InvoiceDt,
TotalPrice from cte where dnrnk=2
```

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT TOP 1 TotalPrice FROM (
  SELECT TOP 2 TotalPrice FROM invoice
  ORDER BY TotalPrice DESC
) AS em ORDER BY TotalPrice ASC
```

Essentially:

Find the top 2 TotalPrice in descending order.
Of those 2, find the top TotalPrice in ascending order.
The selected value is the second-highest TotalPrice.
If the TotalPrice isn't distinct, you can use `SELECT DISTINCT TOP ...` instead.